# Deploying Django on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: django, apache2, windows-server-2008, mod-wsgi, m2crypto

There is an existing Django project that I am going to deploy on Windows 2008 Server. All required python libs have been installed. To check if everything is good I use python manage.py runserver command, so the project works fine. After that I try configure that project for Apache 2.2 + WSGI and get the following error:

```
Exception Value:    DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\M2Crypto\__init__.py in , line 22
```

**Environment**
Windows 2008 Server R2 Enterprise x64
Python 2.7 x86
MySQL 5.5 x86
OpenSSL 1.0.0c x86
...all other python libs are built for x86

There are paths in system PATH for OpenSSL/Python libs.

How can resolve this?

Thank you in advance.

-Viktor